Microsoft Excel VBA Script
Okay so I am trying to map data and on the following line wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 5).value = "=+Financials!B1" what I want is that after mapping my column should have this Formula "=+Financials!B1" instead what I get is value of that column, I have tried multiple approaches including Copy Paste the column and  wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 5).Formula = "=+Financials!B1" but nothing has worked so far as whatever I try it fetches the value instead of adding the formula. The value in column Financials B1 will change after the mapping.
Any Ideas how I can fix this issue?
    wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 2).value = "project_type"
    wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 4).value = "year_in_files"
    wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 5).value = "=+Financials!B1"
    wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 7).value = companyName
    wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 8).value = projectName ```


Unable to repro. This writes  a formula that references Financials!B1. Do you have any other code modifying the sheet?

If your sheet is named +Financials, use ... .Formula = "='+Financials'!B1".

Rather than repeating lastRowTarget + 1 in the code consider using With
With wsTarget.Rows(lastRowTarget + 1)
    .Columns("B") = "project_type"
    .Columns("D") = "year_in_files"
    .Columns("E").Formula = "=Financials!B1"
    .Columns("G") = companyName
    .Columns("H") = projectName
End With


What I think you are asking for, is writing a formula to a cell. The issue arises because the .Value property assigns the result of the formula (its value) rather than the formula itself. To insert the formula so that it remains dynamic and updates with changes to the referenced cell, you need to use the .Formula property explicitly.
wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 2).Value = "project_type"
wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 4).Value = "year_in_files"
wsTarget.Cells(lastRowTarget + 1, 5).Formula = "=Financials!B1"

By the way, you do not need to use the plus sign after the equal sign in a formula.

.Value doesn't assign the result of a formula, right? For example, ActiveCell.Value = "=1" writes =1 to a cell, not 1. I think there's something missing from the question. Definitely agree with the more explicit .Formula here over .Value though.
